# x=1 is the/a root of (x-1)(x-2)

Tags: articles, mathematics

I have a question about a/the in mathematics.

I would like to say that x=1 is a/the root of the polynomial (x-1)(x-2).

There are two roots of this polynomial, that is, x=1,2.
So x=1 is "a" root of the polynomial? Or should it be "the"?

Comment: If there is more than one, use either _a_ or _one_.

Comment: @J.R. Thank you. If we don't know how many roots are there, should I use "a" root?

Comment: @Eng I would suggest that if you don't know whether other roots exist, that by default to use "a". "The", being the definite article, presupposes that you know there to be only one.

Comment: Your question about how to express things in math is answered here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolynomialRoots.html

Answer (score 5):

As J.R. mentions in his comment, if there is more than one something in a list you can either say "a [something]" or "one of the [somethings]"

> *Goodfellas* is a Martin Scorsese film.
>
> *Goodfellas* is one of Martin Scorsese's films.

So "1" is either "a root" or "one of the roots" of the equation.

Answer (score 4):

Use "the" when there is only one root.  Use "a" when there is more than one root, or you don't know the exact number of roots.